# Extract Information From a File

Tags: python

I have some 40,000 lines of information in a file that I would like to extract the IP addresses of a certain system using Python 3.4.  The file is broken into each block starting with "lease" and ends with "}".  I would like to search for the "SYSTEM123456789" and extract the IP address "10.0.0.2".  How do I go about doing that and what is the preferred approach?

1) Read in the file, break them up in the list, and then search?
2) Copy the file and then search within that file?

```
lease 10.0.0.1 {
  starts 1 2015/06/29 07:22:01;
  ends 2 2015/06/30 07:22:01;
  tstp 2 2015/06/30 07:22:01;
  cltt 1 2015/06/29 07:22:01;
  binding state active; 
  next binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 08:2e:5f:f0:8b:a1;
}
lease 10.0.0.2{
  starts 1 2015/06/29 07:31:20;
  ends 2 2015/06/30 07:31:20;
  tstp 2 2015/06/30 07:31:20;
  cltt 1 2015/06/29 07:31:20;
  binding state active; 
  next binding state free;
  hardware ethernet ec:b1:d7:87:6f:7a;
  uid "\001\354\261\327\207oz";
  client-hostname "SYSTEM123456789";
}
```

Comment: Are the `lease..}` blocks stored in different lines? Also show us what you have tried.

Comment: Haven't tried as I don't know where to start.  I would break each block and store it in a list.  Next I would break it using the ' ; ' delimiter.  Search for the SYSTEM123456789 and search the list [0] to find the IPs using startswith ("leases").

Comment: That looks fine. Why don't you try writing the code for it?

Comment: Are you ever going to find "SYSTEM123456789" without the ip address being 10.0.0.2? I'm assuming you will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the sections with groupby using lease as the delimiter:

```
from itertools import groupby

def find_ip(s, f):
    with open(f) as f:
        grouped = groupby(f, key=lambda x: x.startswith("lease "))
        for k, v in grouped:
            if k: # v is the lease line
                # get ip from lease line
                ip = next(v).rstrip().split()[1]
                # call next to get next element from our groupby object 
                # which is each section after lease 
                val = list(next(grouped)[1])[-2]
                # check for substring
                if val.find(s) != -1:
                    return ip.rstrip("{")
    return "No match"
```

Using your input file:

```
In [5]: find_ip('"SYSTEM123456789"',"in.txt")
Out[5]: '10.0.0.2'
```

`x.startswith("lease ")` as the key to groupby splits the file into sections, `if k` is True we have a line with `lease` so we extract the ip then check the second last line in the lease section and if we find the substring then return the ip.

The file gets split into sections of lines which look like the following:

```
['  starts 1 2015/06/29 07:22:01;\r\n', '  ends 2 2015/06/30 07:22:01;\r\n', '  tstp 2 2015/06/30 07:22:01;\r\n', '  cltt 1 2015/06/29 07:22:01;\r\n', '  binding state active; \r\n', '  next binding state free;\r\n', '  hardware ethernet 08:2e:5f:f0:8b:a1;\r\n', '}\r\n']
['  starts 1 2015/06/29 07:31:20;\r\n', '  ends 2 2015/06/30 07:31:20;\r\n', '  tstp 2 2015/06/30 07:31:20;\r\n', '  cltt 1 2015/06/29 07:31:20;\r\n', '  binding state active; \r\n', '  next binding state free;\r\n', '  hardware ethernet ec:b1:d7:87:6f:7a;\r\n', '  uid "\\001\\354\\261\\327\\207oz";\r\n', '  client-hostname "SYSTEM123456789";\r\n', '}']
```

You can see the second last element is `client-hostname` so we extract that each time and search for the substring.

If the substring can appear anywhere you could use any and check each line:

```
def find_ip(s, f):
    with open(f) as f:
        grouped = groupby(f, key=lambda x: x.startswith("lease "))
        for k, v in grouped:
            if k: # v is the lease line
                # get ip from lease line
                ip = next(v).rstrip().split()[1]
                # call next to get next element from our groupby object
                # which is each section after lease
                val = next(grouped)[1]
                # check for substring
                if any(sub.find(s) != -1 for sub in val):
                    return ip.rstrip("{")
    return "No match"
```

You could apply the same logic just iterating over the file object with an outer an inner loop, when you find a line that starts with "lease " begin the inner loop until you find the substring and return the ip or break the inner loop when you hit a `}` signalling the end of the section.

```
def find_ip(s, f):
    with open(f) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith("lease "):
                ip = line.rstrip().split()[1]
                for n_line in f:
                    if n_line.find(s) != -1:
                        return ip.rstrip("{")
                    if n_line.startswith("}"):
                        break
    return "No match"
```

Output:

```
In [9]: find_ip('"SYSTEM123456789"',"in.txt")
Out[9]: '10.0.0.2'
```

neither approach involves storing more than one section of lines in memory at any one time.

Comment: This itertool black magic works.  Your post is very detailed and can be easily followed.  I think itertool is more efficient than nesting 2 for loops.

Comment: The itertools approach a  bit more concise and nicer to look at anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what @Ijk mentioned, I came up with this.

```
import re

find_ip = False

with open(f) as f:
    for line in f:
        mat = re.match(r'lease ([0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*).*', line, re.M)
        if mat:
            ip = mat.group(1)
        mat = re.match(r'.* ("SYSTEM123456789").*', line, re.M)
        if mat:
            print(ip)
```

OP asked for a preffered approach and this is mine although I'm not the best with regex. Still, I think that's what OP was looking for.

I changed the regex for the ip address so it can find random ip's and will print the ip only if it finds the SYSTEM name

Comment: This would be the approach that I might end up but the IPs are random.  The key here is not to base the search on the IPs but the system's name.  Thank you for contributing.